error in recontructuion function of SA attack algorithm for CB systems
I try to execute the attached code in the following link:
https://github.com/biometricsecurity/Preimage-attack-on-BTP-template
The code aims to measure the similarity attacks at CB systems. I have tried to run the example of Biohahing and it works with no errors. I have changed the functions of Biohash by IoM functions, but the reconstruction function doesn’t work. I need your help to solve the problem. The code is attached.
Thanks in advance
function [randum] = random_IoM_edit(orig_length,Ndimension,Nprojection)


randum = randn(orig_length,Ndimension,Nprojection);

end


function [transformed_templates] = IoM_edit(opts)

persons=opts.nopersons;
for i=1:persons
    training_vector=opts.data(i,:);
 maxout_code_training_ind = [];
 for counter = 1:opts.Nprojection
            
            tmp_training= training_vector* opts.model(:,:,counter);
            [m_trainig ind_training] = max(tmp_training);
            maxout_code_training_ind = [maxout_code_training_ind, ind_training];
 end
 transformed_templates(i,:)=maxout_code_training_ind;
end




function [distance] = fitness_iom_edit(x, hashcode,opts)

 [transformed_data] = IoM_edit(opts);

distcc=[];
for a=1:size(hashcode,1)
    distcc=[distcc  1-matching_IoM(hashcode(a,:),transformed_data)];
end
distance=mean(distcc);


end


and the main mat file is:
%clear all;
close all;
load('data\lfw\LFW_10Samples_insightface.mat')
load('data\lfw\LFW_label_10Samples_insightface.mat')
labels=ceil(0.1:0.1:158);

addpath('matlab_tools');
addpath_recurse("btp")
    opts.data= LFW_10Samples_insightface
    opts.Ndimension= 50;
    opts.Nprojection = 300;
    opts.nopersons=size(LFW_10Samples_insightface,1);
    opts.dX=size(LFW_10Samples_insightface,2);
    opts.model = random_IoM_edit(opts.dX,opts.Ndimension,opts.Nprojection);
    
    
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    %% facenet iom generate dataset
[transformed_data] = IoM_edit(opts);
    
    
    %scores = 1- pdist2(transformed_data,transformed_data,'Hamming');
    %hamming_gen_score = scores(labels'==labels);
    %hamming_gen_score = hamming_gen_score(find(hamming_gen_score~=1));
    %hamming_imp_score = scores(labels'~=labels);
    
    
    %[EER_HASH, mTSR, mFAR, mFRR, mGAR] =computeperformance(hamming_gen_score, hamming_imp_score, 0.001);  % isnightface 3.43 % 4.40 %
    reconstruct_x=zeros(158,512);
    
    %% reconstruct the first one
    for i=1:158
        disp(['reconstructing ',num2str(i)])
        to_retrieve_hash=transformed_data((i-1)*10+1,:); % first of the template are used to reconstruct
        %rng default % For reproducibility
        f_fitness = @(x)fitness_iom_edit(x,to_retrieve_hash,opts); % fitness function
         f_constr = []; 
         
        reconstruct_x(i,:) = reconstruct(f_fitness,f_constr,opts);  
    end
    
    
    save(['data/iomhashing_reconstructnoconstraint_',num2str(dimensions),'.mat'],'reconstruct_x');
    save(['data/iomhashing_eer_',num2str(dimensions),'.mat'],'EER_HASH');



i have chanced Biohashing by anther IoM function, reconstruct fuuction donot construct the required matrix

I think the problem you're facing is with the reconstruction function in the IoM algorithm after replacing Biohashing with IoM. Since the reconstruction function isn't working, it could be related to how to fitness function fitness_iom_edit is being defined and used (or possibly how thee data is being reconstructed or processed).
What I would recommend you do is to check your input dimensions and make sure the reconstruct functions are consistent with requirements.
Secondly, you should debug the fitness function. The fitness_iom_edit function computes the distance between the original hashcode and the new data via matching_IoM.
Thirdly, validate the reconstruct function as it might need modifications to work with IoM.
You should also confirm that the initialization of the opts structure is correct for IoM (including opts.model).
Here is some code for debugging:
function [distance] = fitness_iom_edit(x, hashcode, opts)
    [transformed_data] = IoM_edit(opts);
    
    distcc = [];
    for a = 1:size(hashcode, 1)
        dist = 1 - matching_IoM(hashcode(a, :), transformed_data);
        distcc = [distcc, dist];
    end
    
    distance = mean(distcc);
    
    % Debugging output
    disp('Fitness function results:');
    disp(['Distance: ', num2str(distance)]);
end

Heres your script edited (what I am assuming to be the script at the top:
function [randum] = random_IoM_edit(orig_length, Ndimension, Nprojection)
    % Generates a random IoM projection matrix
    % orig_length: Length of the original vector
    % Ndimension: Target dimension for IoM
    % Nprojection: Number of projections

    % Preallocate the output matrix
    randum = randn(orig_length, Ndimension, Nprojection);
end

function [transformed_templates] = IoM_edit(opts)
    % Applies IoM transformation to the input data
    % opts: Struct containing the necessary options and data

    persons = opts.nopersons;
    Nprojection = opts.Nprojection;

    % Preallocate transformed templates matrix
    transformed_templates = zeros(persons, Nprojection);

    for i = 1:persons
        training_vector = opts.data(i, :);
        maxout_code_training_ind = zeros(1, Nprojection); % Preallocate
        
        for counter = 1:Nprojection
            % Perform the matrix multiplication and find the max index
            tmp_training = training_vector * opts.model(:, :, counter);
            [~, ind_training] = max(tmp_training);
            maxout_code_training_ind(counter) = ind_training;
        end
        
        % Store the transformed template for the current person
        transformed_templates(i, :) = maxout_code_training_ind;
    end
end

function [distance] = fitness_iom_edit(x, hashcode, opts)
    % Computes the fitness distance for IoM
    % x: Candidate solution
    % hashcode: The hashcode to compare against
    % opts: Struct containing necessary options and data

    opts.data = x; % Update opts with the current candidate solution

    % Transform the candidate data using IoM
    transformed_data = IoM_edit(opts);

    % Calculate the distance between hashcode and transformed data
    num_codes = size(hashcode, 1);
    distcc = zeros(1, num_codes); % Preallocate the distance array
    
    for a = 1:num_codes
        distcc(a) = 1 - matching_IoM(hashcode(a, :), transformed_data);
    end
    
    % Return the mean distance as the fitness value
    distance = mean(distcc);
end

I also do belive you have made a type in the variable m_trainig instead of m_training I have corrected this.
This should initialize your arrays properly. I'm not in a location at the moment to test this out. If there are any problems I will edit post.

Thanks a lot for your help. I have excuted the code with your modifications. I have the following error from fitness_iom_edit line 7 opts.data = x;
